# Looking for a Cppcheck-like tool for Java development

Tags: java, c++, pmd, cppcheck

I'm a software tester and developer. My company is starting a partnership with another development team and we need a new tool for static analysis.

The new team's previous code is written in Java, so we need a static analysis tool with similar features to Cppcheck. We have been trying Macker, PMD and JDepend but none of these are like Cppcheck.

Also, we are trying to get a trial license of Coverity, which it seems like we want, but at the moment I couldn't test it yet.

So, does anyone know of a tool like the one I'm looking for? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207652/how-do-commercial-java-static-analysis-tools-compare-with-the-free-ones

Comment: It seems from reading the wiki page of cppcheck, lots of the stuff it checks is unnecessary in Java (not many unintialized variables, deprecated warnings are shown by every IDE I'm aware,..). What features are you looking for exactly? checkstyle and FindBugs are some other possible tools you may want to investigate. Have made good experiences with both of those for finding bad code style and likely errors.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org). This tool provides a broad analysis of your Java code. Examples can be found [here](https://sonarcloud.io/about).