# Finding most commonly edited files in clearcase

Tags: version-control, refactoring, clearcase

We are currently planning a quality improvement exercise and i would like to target the most commonly edited files in our clearcase vobs. Since we have just been through a bug fixing phase the most commonly edited files should give a good indication of where the most bug prone code is, and therefore the most in need of quality improvment.

Does anyone know if there is a way of obtaining a top 100 list of most edited files? Preferably this would cover edits that are happening on multiple branches.

Comment: I will update my answer later this evening

Comment: Answer updated (added actually) for multiple-branch count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The previous answer was for a [simpler case: single branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576960/finding-most-commonly-edited-files-in-clearcase/1577623#1577623))

Since "most projects dev has not all happened on the one branch so the version numbers don't necessarily mean most edited",  a "way to get number of check-ins across all branches" would be:

- search all versions created since the date of the last bug fixing phase,
- sort them by file,
- then by occurrence.

Something along the lines of:

```
C:\Prog\cc\test\test>ct find -all -type f -ver "created_since(16-Oct-2009)" -exec "cleartool descr -fmt """%En~%Sn\n""""""%CLEARCASE_XPN%"""" | grep -v "\\0" | awk -F ~ "{print $1}" | sort | uniq -c | sort /R | head -100
```

Or, for Unix syntax:

```
$ ct find -all -type f -ver 'created_since(16-Oct-2009)' -exec 'cleartool descr -fmt "%En~%Sn\n" "%CLEARCASE_XPN%"' | grep -v "/0"  | awk -F ~ '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -100
```

- replace the date by the one of the label marking the start of your bug-fixing phase
- Again, note the double-quotes around the '`%CLEARCASE_XPN%`' to accommodate spaces within file names.
- Here,  '`%CLEARCASE_XPN%`' is used rather than '`%CLEARCASE_PN%`' because we need every versions.
- `grep -v "/0"` is here to exclude version 0 (`/main/0`, `/main/myBranch/0`, ...)
- `awk -F ~ "{print $1}"` is used to only print the first part of each line:
  `C:\Prog\cc\test\test\a.txt~\main\mybranch\2` becomes `C:\Prog\cc\test\test\a.txt`
- From there, the counting and sorting can begin:

  - `sort` to make sure every identical line is grouped
  - `uniq -c` to remove duplicate lines and precede each remaining line with a count of said duplicates
  - `sort -rn` (or `sort /R` for Windows) for having the most edited files at the top
  - `head -100` for keeping only the 100 most edited files.

Again, GnuWin32 will come in handy for the Windows version of the one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

(See answer for [more complicated case: multiple branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576960/finding-most-commonly-edited-files-in-clearcase/1580802#1580802))

First, use a dynamic view: easier and quicker to update its content and fiddle with its config spec rules.

If your bug-fixing has been made in a branch, starting from a given label, set-up a dynamic view with the following config spec as:

```
element * .../MY_BRANCH/LATEST
element * MY_STARTING_LABEL
element * /main/LATEST
```

Then you find all files, with their current version number (closely related to the number of edits)

```
ct find . -type f -exec "cleartool desc -fmt """%Ln\t\t%En\n""" """%CLEARCASE_PN%""""|sort /R|head -100
```

This is the Windows syntax (nothe the triple "double-quotes" around `%CLEARCASE_PN%` in order to accommodate spaces within the file names.

the '`head`' command comes from the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) library.
The most edited version are at the top of the list.

A Unix version would be:

```
$ ct find . -type f -exec 'cleartool desc -fmt "%Ln\t\t%En\n" "$CLEARCASE_PN"' | sort -rn | head -100
```

The most edited version would be at the top.

Do not forget that for metrics, the raw numbers are not enough, [trends are important too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195887/what-is-the-fascination-with-code-metrics/195932#195932).

Comment: I really like your answer but as with most projects dev has not all happened on the one branch so the version numbers don't necessarily mean most edited. Is there a way to get number of check-ins across all branches?